# Is it right to distribute one app to different apple VPP clients using same bundle identifier through B2B account?

Tags: ios, iphone, b2b, apple-vpp

Do we need separate bundle identifiers for the same app to distribute to different clients through B2B account? I have different clients and I need to distribute same app to them. Can I do it using same bundle identifier.I have apple B2B account for this distribution. Please guide how good is this to maintain different versions for different clients.

Comment: You can simply change the version for different clients and keep the same bundle identifier. And If you want to keep them separate then just create a new target and then share the different targets of same app with different clients. Its up to you that you want to use same bundle identifier or different.

Comment: Thank you for the information. One more doubt, If I publish a new version customized for a particular client, do other clients get the version notification?

Comment: If you will publish on App Store with same identifier then everyone will get update for that. If you want to maintain update separately then you should use different bundle identifiers in your targets.

Comment: Thank you. I think I better maintain separate bundle identifier then.

Comment: Yes ! I think so...